# Is there a way to detect color with turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-turtle

Right i know this has been asked a million times but all the answers are from years ago. I've got a couple of game ideas and they require detecting colors I'm doing this at school where the IT staff have done a very good job of locking everything down so I can't get modules that don't come as stock. If this cannot be done fairly simply then I've had an idea where it could record the position of where it drew the lines and check if the player goes to those locations but have no idea where to start with that. Can any one help?

This is the game it's a dungeon crawler very much still in development.

```
import turtle

player=turtle.Turtle()
level=turtle.Turtle()
health = 100

player.shape('circle')

level.hideturtle()
level.speed(10)

level.penup()
level.forward(100)
level.right(90)
for _ in range(4):
    level.forward(10)
    level.pendown()
    level.forward(90)
    level.right(90)
    level.forward(90)
    level.penup()
    level.forward(10)

player.penup()
while True:
    move = input()
    if move == 'w':
        player.setheading(90)
        player.forward(10)
    if move == 'a':
        player.setheading(180)
        player.forward(10)
    if move == 's':
        player.setheading(270)
        player.forward(10)
    if move == 'd':
        player.setheading(0)
        player.forward(10)
    if health <= 10:
        player.color('red')
```

Comment: Turtle doesn't have inbuilt collision, but one option would be to make the walls (or object you want to collide with) separate turtles, and write your own collision logic using the distance between the player and the other turtles. This comment shows 
the method.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081463/11825005

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make a Python Turtle detect if it's touching a specific colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66819769/can-you-make-a-python-turtle-detect-if-its-touching-a-specific-colour)

Answer (score 1):

This is not within the defined capabilities of the turtle library.  However, if you're using turtle built atop tkinter, then you can drop down a level and get what you need.  (This wouldn't be an additional module as turtle's already using tkinter in this situation.)  Some examples:

[Can you make a Python Turtle detect if it's touching a specific colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70561912/5771269)

[Turtle Graphics - Extract Color from onscreenclick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47384381/5771269)

[python canvas.find_overlapping appears to have inverted y-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52751855/5771269)

Unfortunately, nothing new here, just old tricks.